# PHP Update Data in MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to Update Data in MySQL using PDO.

I have set up the code below but get the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in >your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version >for the right syntax to use near '(h1, text) values ('Blah blah' at line 1

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))://if admin wants to edit category

$h1 = $_POST['h1'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE sections (h1, text) values (:h1, :text) WHERE id=1');
$stmt->bindParam(':h1', $h1);   
$stmt->bindParam(':text', $text);   
// execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update syntax** should be:

```
UPDATE table_name SET `field1` = new-value1, `field2` = new-value2.
```

Your query should be:

```
UPDATE sections SET `h1` = :h1, `text` = :text WHERE id = 1;
```

See the [Update query syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

Answer (score 0):

text is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql.

Write your query as below:-

```
UPDATE sections SET `h1` = :h1, `text` = :text WHERE id = 1;
```